# changing calculate button to restart button after clicked

Tags: vb.net

Is there any way to change a button to another button while running the program, i.e when the user clicks a button called "display", it calculates the results, then "display" turns into "Restart?" and if the user clicks that it restarts the program?  I would like to change btnDisplay to btnRestart:

```
Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    ' displays a student's grade

    Double.TryParse(txtEarned.Text, dblEarned)

    For Each minimum As Double In dblMinimumPoints
        If dblEarned >= minimum Then
            lblGrade.Text = strGrade(gradeIndex)
            gradeIndex += 1
        End If
    Next

    txtEarned.ReadOnly = False
    btnDisplay.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your handler  onclick and add a select case based on the .text attribute, then if the text is display update it it to restart, if it is restart then add a goto to where you want the script to start from on restart.

EDIT, below I have added the codetorun as a function which is probably a better solution than goto:

```
Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

        Select Case btnDisplay.Text
            Case "Submit"
                codeiwanttorun()
                btnDisplay.Text = "Restart"
            Case "Restart"
                codeiwanttorun()

        End Select

    End Sub


    Private Function codeiwanttorun()
        Double.TryParse(txtEarned.Text, dblEarned)

        For Each minimum As Double In dblMinimumPoints
            If dblEarned >= minimum Then
                lblGrade.Text = strGrade(gradeIndex)
                gradeIndex += 1
            End If
        Next
    End Function
```

Comment: can you give me an example?  I am not familiar with select case.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in replying, I have updated my post, see if that helps

Comment: no problem buddy, ill look into select case some more, it looks very useful.

Comment: If it doesnt update the text, then just insert Application.DoEvents() after  btnDisplay.Text = "Restart"

Answer (score 2):

I suppose there are multiple ways to do this. One is to have two buttons, `btnDisplay` and `btnRestart`, each with desired `Text`, that are laid on top of each other in the form designer. Alternate which one is visible when they are clicked.

```
Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
' displays a student's grade

Double.TryParse(txtEarned.Text, dblEarned)

For Each minimum As Double In dblMinimumPoints
    If dblEarned >= minimum Then
        lblGrade.Text = strGrade(gradeIndex)
        gradeIndex += 1
    End If
Next

txtEarned.ReadOnly = False
btnDisplay.Visible = False
btnReset.Visible = True

End Sub
```

I'm not sure what you mean by saying that `btnRestart` will "restart the program", but presumably in its click event you would likewise hide it and make `btnDisplay` visible again.

(Also you might want to add some `Try...Finally` error handling in these events, so that even if something goes wrong, you can be sure the `Visible` lines will be executed.)